# How to get all orders last 30 days with date range using codeigniter PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, database, codeigniter

Here is my table and I need to fetch all data from my MySQL database that will display the 30 days counting the total number of orders per day. And also there will be a date range.

**Example 1:** Current date is Aug 08, 2016. I need to display the last 30 days from Aug 08, 2016.

```
Order table

id | customer_id | num_of_order |date
---+-------------+--------------+--------      
1  |    10001    |      1       | 2016-08-08 07:23:50 
2  |    10002    |      4       | 2016-08-07 11:33:50  
3  |    10003    |      2       | 2016-08-06 15:44:50 //same day 
4  |    10001    |      5       | 2016-08-06 20:50:50 //same day
5  |    10004    |      3       | 2016-08-04 11:17:50
```

now for expected output it will display:

```
array (
    [0] => array (
        [date] => 2016-08-08
        [total_orders] => 1
    )
    [1] => array (
        [date] => 2016-08-07
        [total_orders] => 4
    )
    [2] => array (
        [date] => 2016-08-06
        [total_orders] => 7
    )
    [3] => array (
        [date] => 2016-08-05
        [total_orders] => 0  //no orders but still need to include in the output
    )
    [4] => array (
        [date] => 2016-08-04
        [total_orders] => 3
    )
    //and so forth (July 09, 2016).....
)
```

Is there any PHP codeigniter code for this?

Comment: [What have you tried so far?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)
Please [edit] your question to show a [mcve] of the code
that you are having problems with, then we can try to help
with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->db->select("DATE_FORMAT(date,'%Y-%m-%d') as covered_date,count(date(date)) AS total_order");
$this->db->from('order');
$this->db->where('date > DATE_SUB( "2016-08-08" , INTERVAL 30 DAY )');
$this->db->group_by("date(date)");
$query = $this->db->get();
$result = $query->result_array();
$start_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-30 day', strtotime($end_date)));
$return = array();

while (strtotime($start_date) <= strtotime($end_date)) {
    $return[] = $start_date;
    $start_date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("+1 day", strtotime($start_date)));
}
print_r($return);
```